# jQuery Dynamic Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple select box on my page with id's `drop_01`, `drop_02` and so on along with a common class.

I am writing a jQuery that whenever a select box is changed, I get the number of selected options for that select box. Following is the jQuery but its not working. Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong.

```
var x = "drop_" + idnum; // (idnum contains the numeric index like 01,02 etc).
var length = $(' "#" + x option:selected').length;
```

But when i give the hard coded id like below, it works fine.

```
var length = $('#drop_02 option:selected').length;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't concatenating the string of the selector properly:

```
var length = $('#' + x + ' option:selected').length;
```

I would strongly suggest you use an editor with syntax highlighting as it makes it virtually impossible to miss errors like this.

Comment: Thanks Rory, I overlooked that one.

Comment: Rory, Can you please tell me how can we use this dynamic id with radio button. In my case 1st time the radio button functionality doesn;t work as intended but after that it works fine. It gives me undefined the 1st time.

var value = $('input:radio[name=drop_'+idnum+']:checked').val();

Comment: You're probably best to start a new question for that.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to post a new question :(

Comment: $('input:radio[name=input_'+ idnum +']').change(function () {
alert("hello");
});
(idnum is the same as above 01,02 etc)
When i first change the value of radio button the above jquery is not triggered and after that it works good.
Any thoughts on this.